# Inherits Dictionary(of TKey, TValue) can´t be case insensitive

Tags: .net, dictionary, case-insensitive

Please, i need help. I have my own class:

```
Public Class SerializableDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Implements IXmlSerializable

....

End Class
```

But, ContainsKey method is case sensitive. I try everything, i need compare string with case insensitive. I think change the CurrentCulture in thread, by i don't found how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only case sensitive if you use a case-sensitive comparer. You need to pass down an insensitive comparer to the base-constructor. In C#, this would be something like:

```
public class SerializableDictionay<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public SerializableDictionay() : base(GetComparer()) { }

    static IEqualityComparer<TKey> GetComparer() {
        if(typeof(TKey) == typeof(string)) {
            // just one of the possibilities
            return (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)(object)
                  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        }
        return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    }
}
```

or, **much** better IMO, let the caller decide:

```
public class SerializableDictionay<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public SerializableDictionay() : base() {}
    public SerializableDictionay(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
              : base(comparer) {}
}
```

(and have the caller initializers specify the string-comparer desired)

Comment: Thanks Marc :D you made my night happier!

Comment: @DamiánHerrera I do thoroughly prefer the second version to the first, note - fewer surprises!

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting from `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` is usually the wrong thing to do - it's usually better to *compose* a collection than to *inherit* from it.

However, you basically need to make sure the dictionary uses a case-insensitive comparer - which you do by passing in something like [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) into the appropriate [constructor overload for `Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx). Think carefully about which culture you want the comparison to be performed in, if any.

You can do this either in your existing class by writing a constructor which calls `MyBase.New(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`:

```
Public Class SerializableDictionary(Of TValue)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, TValue)
    Implements IXmlSerializable

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that the fixing it to use a `string` key type - it would be slightly unusual for it to "know" about one particular key type separately, but still be generic.

Or you can just pass it into the constructor as normal if you go with the composition route.